# Linear Transformation of an Inner Product Space

Tags: linear-algebra

My professor posted a question asking.

"Let V be an inner product space with a subspace W having B as an orthonormal basis. Show that the function T: V → W is a linear transformation. T is called the orthogonal projection of V onto W."

I have begun to answer the question by trying to prove vector addition and scalar multiplication but I am having trouble understanding how to begin.

Comment: How is $T$ defined?

Answer (score 0):

Extend $B$ to a basis of V by appending necessary elements. Then the span of such added elements will form an orthogonal complement of $W$ call it $U$. Hence $V = U \oplus W$. Then each $v \in V$ can be written uniquely as $v = u + w$.

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be scalars. Let $v_{1}, v_{2} \in V$. Then $v_{1} = u_{1} + w_{1}$ and $v_{2} = u_{2} + w_{2}$.

Then $T(\alpha v_{1} + \beta v_{2}) = T((\alpha u_{1} + \beta u_{2}) + (\alpha w_{1} + \beta w_{2})) = ?$